# How to escape double-quotes in a double-quoted string literal

Tags: php, whitespace

This is weird, I can't figure it out :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[TestTbl] WHERE Agentd_ID = "$_SESSION['agentid']" ";
```

I also tried:

```
 $query ='SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[TestTbl] WHERE Agentd_ID = "$_SESSION['agentid']" ';
```

I would really appreciate any help from you guys :D

Comment: What exactly is the problem you can't figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        [master].[dbo].[TestTbl]
    WHERE
        Agentd_ID = \"{$_SESSION['agentid']}\"
";
```

**BUT** have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
and then look for the approriate encoding/escaping function for your database (t-sql?) and/or prepared statements with parameters.

see also:
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: great. thanks.. But I am having error now :/
This works a while ago, when I set Agent_ID = '1234', but when i tried the session you've said, this part got some errors:
while($record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY){

Comment: Take a look at the error handling in http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#example-2378

Comment: No worries with regards to the sql-injection part, I'll cover it soon. :D

Comment: It works now, thank you very much sir, I owe you one :D, I just removed changed the " to ' and removed the / before the {  
Thank you sir.